# SSL client-server encryption and authentication

Tags: java, authentication, encryption, ssl-certificate

I need to have one client and one server to communicate with each other on a secure channel. The client is a Java app, the server is a ucspi-ssl server, here for more details: https://www.fehcom.de/ipnet/ucspi-ssl/man/sslserver.1.html.
I want communication to be simple, without using http.

What I am trying to achieve:

1. Communication has to be encrypted;
2. Server has to authenticate the client.

Here is what I have done so far:

1. Created client private key and client self signed certificate:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout client-key.pem -x509 -days 365 -out client-certificate.pem
```

2. Inserted both private key and certificate into client keystore:

```
openssl pkcs12 -inkey client-key.pem -in client-certificate.pem -export -out client-certificate.p12
```

3. Created server private key and server self signed certificate:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout server-key.pem -x509 -days 365 -out server-certificate.pem
```

4. Added server certificate to client truststore:

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -file server-certificate.pem -keypass password -storepass password -keystore clienttruststore.jks
```

5. Created DH param file:

```
openssl dhparam -out /etc/ssl/dh2048.pem 2048
```

At this point, If I were using a Java SSL server I would specify the server keystore containing the server certificate and private keyand the server truststore filled with the client certificate it needs to validate. But in ucspi-ssl server implementation there is no concept of keystore or truststore. For what my understanding is, given environment variables need to be set:

> X509 certificate and encryption options:
>
> ```
>    -3     Read a null-terminated key password from file descriptor 3.
>
>    -m     (Mail.) Require valid client certificates, but don't check for
>           matching FQDN.
>
>    -z     (Host.) Require valid client certificates and match FQDN (if
>           given) against SAN/DN.
>
>    -Z     (Default.) Do not require client certificates.
> ```
>
> SSL ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES READ
>
> ```
>    These variables define the run-time environment of sslserver and are
>    used to specify X509 certificates and keyfile per connection.
>
>    $SSL_USER=name
>           The user, reading the certificates and keyfile.
>
>    $SSL_GROUP=group
>           The respective user group.
>
>    $SSL_UID=uid
>           The numerical UID of the $SSL_USER.
>
>    $SSL_CHROOT=path
>           Perform reading of certificates and keyfile in a $SSL_CHROOT
>           jail.
>
>    $CAFILE=path
>           If set, overrides the compiled-in CA file name.  The CA file
>           contains the list of CAs used to verify the client certificate.
>           Certificates in $CAFILE are processed when the server starts.
>
>    $CADIR=path
>           If set, overrides the compiled-in CA directory name.  The CA
>           directory contains certificates files used to verify the client
>           certificate.  This list augments the list from $CAFILE.
>           Certificates in $CADIR are processed during certificate
>           verification.
>
>    $CERTFILE=path
>           If set, overrides the compiled-in certificate file name.  The
>           server presents this certificate to clients.
>
>    $CERTCHAINFILE=path
>           If set, overrides the compiled-in certificate chainfile name.
>           The server presents this list of certificats to clients.  Note:
>           Providing $CERTCHAINFILE has precedence over $CERTFILE.
>           Certificates in this file needs to be 'ordered' starting from
>           the uppermost root certificates and placing your host's
>           it's certificate.
>
>    $VERIFYDEPTH=n
>           If set, overrides the compiled-in verification depth. Default:
>           1.
>
>    $CCAFILE=path
>           If set, overrides the compiled-in client CA file name for client
>           certificate request.  The client CA file contains the list of
>           CAs sent to the client when requesting a client certificate.
>           Note: Setting of $CCAFILE is required while using the option -z
>           or -m.  However, declaring $CCAFILE="-" disables (on a per-
>           connection base) the client certificate request.
>
>    $CCAVERIFY
>           If set, sslserver requests a valid client certificate on a per-
>           connection base, unlike the general option -z.
> ```
>
> SSL ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES SET
>
> ```
>    In case sslserver is called with the option -e, the following mod_ssl
>    environment variables are provided:
>
>    SSL_PROTOCOL
>           The TLS protocol version (SSLv3, TLSv1, ...).
>
>    SSL_SESSION_ID
>           The hex-encoded SSL session id.
>
>    SSL_CIPHER
>           The cipher specification name.
>
>    SSL_CIPHER_USEKEYSIZE
>           Number of cipher bits (actually used).
>
>    SSL_CIPHER_ALGKEYSIZE
>           Number of cipher bits (possible).
>
>    SSL_VERSION_INTERFACE
>           The mod_ssl program version.
>
>    SSL_VERSION_LIBRARY
>           The OpenSSL program version.
>
>    SSL_CLIENT_M_VERSION
>           The version of the client certificate.
>
>    SSL_CLIENT_M_SERIAL
>           The serial of the client certificate.
>
>    SSL_CLIENT_S_DN
>           Subject DN in client's certificate.
>
>
>    SSL_CLIENT_A_SIG
>           Algorithm used for the signature of client's certificate.
>
>    SSL_CLIENT_A_KEY
>           Algorithm used for the public key of client's certificate.
>
>    SSL_CLIENT_CERT
>           PEM-encoded client certificate.
>
>    SSL_CLIENT_CERT_CHAIN n
>           PEM-encoded certificates in client certificate chain.
>
>    SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY
>           NONE, SUCCESS, GENEROUS or FAILED:reason.
>
>    SSL_SERVER_M_SERIAL
>           The serial of the server certificate.
>
>    SSL_SERVER_S_DN
>           Subject DN in server's certificate.
>
>    SSL_SERVER_S_DN_x509
>           Component of server's Subject DN.
>
>    SSL_SERVER_I_DN
>           Issuer DN of server's certificate.
>
>    SSL_SERVER_I_DN_x509
>           Component of server's Issuer DN.
>
>    SSL_SERVER_V_START
>           Validity of server's certificate (start time).
>
>    SSL_SERVER_V_END
>           Validity of server's certificate (end time).
>
>    SSL_SERVER_A_SIG
>           Algorithm used for the signature of server's certificate.
>
>    SSL_SERVER_A_KEY
>           Algorithm used for the public key of server's certificate.
>
>    SSL_SERVER_CERT
>           PEM-encoded server certificate.
> ```

**How can I inform ucspi-ssl server that the client certificate can be trusted and perform client authentication?**

I have tried to run the server with the following command:

```
sslserver -v -m  localhost 12345 ./some_script.sh
```

with the following environment variables set:

```
DHFILE=/etc/ssl/dh2048.pem
CERTFILE=server-certificate.pem
KEYFILE=server-key.pem
```

Here is the java SSL client code:

```
try {
           // Client key store
           System.setProperty("https.protocols", "SSLv3");
           System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "all");
           KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
           String password = "password";
           InputStream inputStream = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/home/centuri0n/reservations/ssl/client-certificate.p12");
           keyStore.load(inputStream, password.toCharArray());

           // Client trust store
           KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
           String password2 = "password";
           TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("PKIX", "SunJSSE");
           InputStream inputStream1 = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/home/centuri0n/reservations/ssl/clienttruststore.jks");
           trustStore.load(inputStream1, password2.toCharArray());
           trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);
           X509TrustManager x509TrustManager = null;
           for (TrustManager trustManager : trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers()) {
               if (trustManager instanceof X509TrustManager) {
                   x509TrustManager = (X509TrustManager) trustManager;
                   break;
               }
           }

           if (x509TrustManager == null) throw new NullPointerException();

           // KeyManagerFactory ()
           KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509", "SunJSSE");
           keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, password.toCharArray());
           X509KeyManager x509KeyManager = null;
           for (KeyManager keyManager : keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers()) {
               if (keyManager instanceof X509KeyManager) {
                   x509KeyManager = (X509KeyManager) keyManager;
                   break;
               }
           }
           if (x509KeyManager == null) throw new NullPointerException();

           // set up the SSL Context
           SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
           sslContext.init(new KeyManager[]{x509KeyManager}, new TrustManager[]{x509TrustManager}, null);

           SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
           SSLSocket kkSocket = (SSLSocket) socketFactory.createSocket("127.0.0.1", 12345);
           kkSocket.setUseClientMode(false);
           kkSocket.setEnabledProtocols(new String[]{"TLSv1","TLSv1.1","TLSv1.2","TLSv1.3"});
           kkSocket.setEnabledCipherSuites(new String[]{"TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384", "TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256", "TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256", "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384", "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256", "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256", "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384", "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256", "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256", "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384", "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256", "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384", "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256", "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256", "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384", "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384", "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256", "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256", "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256", "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256", "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256", "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256", "TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384", "TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384", "TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256", "TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256", "TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384", "TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384", "TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256", "TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256", "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA", "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA", "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA", "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA", "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA", "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA", "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA", "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA", "TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA", "TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA", "TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA", "TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA", "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384", "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256", "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256", "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256", "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA", "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA", "TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV"
           });

           PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(kkSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
           BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                   new InputStreamReader(kkSocket.getInputStream()));

           BufferedReader stdIn =
                   new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
           String fromServer;
           String fromUser;

           while ((fromServer = in.readLine()) != null) {
               System.out.println("Server: " + fromServer);
               if (fromServer.equals("Bye."))
                   break;

               fromUser = stdIn.readLine();
               if (fromUser != null) {
                   System.out.println("Client: " + fromUser);
                   out.println(fromUser);
               }
           }
       }catch (IOException e){
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
           throw new RuntimeException(e);
       } catch (CertificateException e) {
           throw new RuntimeException(e);
       } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
           throw new RuntimeException(e);
       } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
           throw new RuntimeException(e);
       } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
           throw new RuntimeException(e);
       }
```

When I start the client, it blocks for about 10 seconds with the following debug messages:

```
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.608 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:397|Ignore disabled cipher suite: SSL_DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.608 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:406|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: SSL_DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.608 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:397|Ignore disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.608 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:406|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.608 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:397|Ignore disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.608 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:406|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.608 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:397|Ignore disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.608 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:406|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.609 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:397|Ignore disabled cipher suite: SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.609 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:406|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.609 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:397|Ignore disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.609 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:406|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.609 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:397|Ignore disabled cipher suite: SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.609 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:406|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.609 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:397|Ignore disabled cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.609 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:406|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.609 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:397|Ignore disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.609 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:406|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.610 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:397|Ignore disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.610 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:406|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.610 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:397|Ignore disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.610 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:406|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.610 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:397|Ignore disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.610 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:406|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.610 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:397|Ignore disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.610 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:406|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.610 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:397|Ignore disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_NULL_SHA
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.610 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:406|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_NULL_SHA
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.611 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:397|Ignore disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.611 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:406|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.612 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:397|Ignore disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.612 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:406|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.612 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:397|Ignore disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.612 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:406|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.613 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:397|Ignore disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.613 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:406|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.613 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:397|Ignore disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.613 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:406|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.613 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:397|Ignore disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.613 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:406|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.613 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:397|Ignore disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.613 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:406|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.613 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:397|Ignore disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.613 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:406|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.615 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:397|Ignore disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.615 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:406|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.615 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:397|Ignore disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.615 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:406|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.615 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:397|Ignore disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.615 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:406|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.615 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:397|Ignore disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.615 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:406|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.616 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:397|Ignore disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.616 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:406|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.616 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:397|Ignore disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.616 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:406|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.616 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:397|Ignore disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.616 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:406|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.617 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:397|Ignore disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.617 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:406|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.617 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:397|Ignore disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.617 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:406|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.618 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:397|Ignore disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.618 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:406|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.618 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:397|Ignore disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.618 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:406|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.618 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:397|Ignore disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.618 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:406|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.618 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:397|Ignore disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.619 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:406|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.619 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:397|Ignore disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.619 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:406|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.621 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:115|trigger seeding of SecureRandom
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.622 CET|SSLContextImpl.java:119|done seeding of SecureRandom
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.627 CET|SSLConfiguration.java:458|System property jdk.tls.client.SignatureSchemes is set to 'null'
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.641 CET|SSLConfiguration.java:458|System property jdk.tls.server.SignatureSchemes is set to 'null'
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.642 CET|HandshakeContext.java:298|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLSv1.2
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.642 CET|HandshakeContext.java:298|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLSv1.2
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-01-27 18:20:41.642 CET|HandshakeContext.java:298|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 for TLSv1.2
```

then, client timeouts and exits:

```
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-01-27 18:21:07.685 CET|SSLSocketInputRecord.java:481|Raw read: EOF
javax.net.ssl|ERROR|10|main|2023-01-27 18:21:07.687 CET|TransportContext.java:363|Fatal (HANDSHAKE_FAILURE): Couldn't kickstart handshaking (
"throwable" : {
  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleEOF(SSLSocketImpl.java:1714)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1513)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1420)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:455)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.ensureNegotiated(SSLSocketImpl.java:920)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:1011)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:270)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:313)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:188)
    at java.base/java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:176)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:162)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:329)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:396)
    at org.example.App.main(App.java:75)
  Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:483)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:472)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:160)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:111)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1505)
    ... 12 more}

)
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10|main|2023-01-27 18:21:07.687 CET|SSLSessionImpl.java:1221|Invalidated session:  Session(1674840041640|SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-01-27 18:21:07.688 CET|SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:71|WRITE: TLSv1.3 alert(handshake_failure), length = 2
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-01-27 18:21:07.688 CET|SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:85|Raw write (
  0000: 15 03 03 00 02 02 28                               ......(
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-01-27 18:21:07.688 CET|SSLSocketImpl.java:1754|close the underlying socket
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-01-27 18:21:07.688 CET|SSLSocketImpl.java:1780|close the SSL connection (passive)
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleEOF(SSLSocketImpl.java:1714)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1513)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1420)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:455)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.ensureNegotiated(SSLSocketImpl.java:920)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:1011)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:270)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:313)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:188)
    at java.base/java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:176)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:162)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:329)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:396)
    at org.example.App.main(App.java:75)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:483)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:472)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:160)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:111)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1505)
    ... 12 more

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: This question appears fairly similar to another question you asked a short time ago: [Java SSL client one way authentication configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75258469/12567365). If they are 2 distinct and separate questions, can you add a note to this question (with a link to the other question) clarifying the difference?

Comment: What's the server log like? It seems to be the part that is timing out, assuming that we get all the log output from the Java (I presume that ALL includes TRACE). It tells that the server is ending the session, so that's a big hint to to look at the other entity/service. Which ciphersuites did you enable on both machines? I see some mention of `SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL` in the exception log, which I don't trust.

Comment: server logs are not eeally helpful, even in verbose mode, it only tells me that tls handshake failed.

Comment: In the client **you've called `setUseClientMode(false)`**. This tells the client to act as a server and wait for the other party to start the handshake -- but the party you're connected to is not a client and never does that. PS: Java 8u291 up and 11.0.11 up won't do TLSv1(.0) or TLSv1.1 even though you enable them. @MaartenBodewes: that's a dummy suite used as a placeholder until the handshake selects a real suite, which in this case didn't happen.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Ah, right. I guess you've found the problem.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Now the client fails with "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_required".

Comment: So (now) you did a handshake but didn't send the client cert. Since you have logging set up, look at it: did you send cert or not? If you did, check _server_ to see why it thinks you didn't, or doesn't accept it. If you didn't, why not? Did server request client cert? Correctly? Does log show loaded keystore contains correct cert and key?

Comment: Yes, I was not sending the client certificate from the server. I did. Now client consumes client certificate request but fails with broken pipe: https://pastebin.com/ibWjsMkm

Comment: However, it fails with broken pipe only if I have setEnabledProtocols(new String[]{"TLSv1.2"}).  If I keep setEnabledProtocols(new String[]{"TLSv1.2", "TLSv1.3"}) it still fails with "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_required".

Comment: Ok I fixed it, I misconfigured some ucspi-ssl server environment variables. This worked for me: CAFILE=client-certificate.pem, CCAFILE=client-certificate.pem, CERT=server-certificate.pem, KEY=server-key.pem, DHPARAM=/etc/ssl/dh2048.pem. Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the formatted and cleaned up Java client code, and ucspi-ssl server environment variables needed to make the ssl communication between the two parties work.

JAVA CLIENT CODE:

```
        try {
    
            System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "all");
    
            String keystore_path = "<keystore_path>";
            String keystore_password = "<keystore_password>";
    
            String truststore_path = "<truststore_path>";
            String truststore_password = "<truststore_password>";
    
            //Keystore
            KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
            keystore.load(new FileInputStream(keystore_path), keystore_password.toCharArray());
            KeyManagerFactory key_manager_factory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
            key_manager_factory.init(keystore, keystore_password.toCharArray());
    
            //Truststore
            KeyStore truststore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
            truststore.load(new FileInputStream(truststore_path), truststore_password.toCharArray());
            TrustManagerFactory trust_manager_factory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            trust_manager_factory.init(truststore);
    
            //SSL Context
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sslContext.init(key_manager_factory.getKeyManagers(), trust_manager_factory.getTrustManagers(), null);
    
            //SSL Socket
            SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
            SSLSocket ssl_socket = (SSLSocket) socketFactory.createSocket("server_ip", 12345);
            ssl_socket.setUseClientMode(true);
            ssl_socket.setEnabledProtocols(new String[]{"TLSv1.3"});
            ssl_socket.setEnabledCipherSuites(new String[]{"TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256", "TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256", "TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"}); //Cyphers supported by both client and ucspi-ssl server
    
    
            //In and out streams
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(ssl_socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ssl_socket.getInputStream()));
    
    //You can now interact with the server using input and output streams
    
    
        } catch (IOException | KeyManagementException | KeyStoreException | UnrecoverableKeyException |
                 CertificateException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
```

SERVER ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES:

- KEYFILE=server-key.pem
- CERTFILE=server-certificate.pem
- CAFILE=client-certificate.pem
- CCAFILE=client-certificate.pem
- DHFILE=/etc/ssl/dh2048.pem

Server is started by launching:

```
sslserver -v -m localhost 12345 ./some_script.sh
```